# How to load checkpoints

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Hi I have tried to load my checkpoints but i get the following error:

" W tensorflow/core/util/tensor_slice_reader.cc:95] Could not open ../codeOutputs/3DNewArchitectureWithRotation: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you need to use a different restore operator?"

This is the code I have used:

```
checkpoint_filepath = '../codeOutputs/3DNewArchitectureWithRotation'
model_checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_filepath,
    monitor='val_loss',
    verbose=0,
    save_best_only=False,
    save_weights_only=False,
    mode='auto',
    save_freq='epoch',
    options=None,
    initial_value_threshold=None,
   
)    




Model.load_weights(checkpoint_filepath)


BestRegressor = Model.fit(aaaiTrainImages, afTrainPorosity, validation_data = (aaaiValidationImages, afValidationPorosity), epochs=Epochs, callbacks =[EarlyStop,model_checkpoint_callback], verbose=2)
```

It seems the file type the checkpoints have been saved as are :HDF document (application/x-hdf).
I would appreciate any help as I have spend many days training my model and suddenly crashed, so it would be really helpful if I can skip retraining it up to the data I had

Comment: Is checkpoint_filepath a directory?  You'd get this error in that case, or if there are data files (no extension), .meta, or .index in the path.

Comment: yes the first part(../codeoutputs)  is a directory but "3DNewArchitectureWithRotation" is the actual file, it has checkpoints stored in it but its an HDF file whichI can't open it with my linux, but it's 23MB. Yeah I didn't use an extension since in the example provided in the following link no extension was used either: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint

Comment: why do you set  `save_weights_only=False` in the callback function and then use `load_weights`? This might be the problem.

Comment: If true then only the model's weights will be saved (model.save_weights(filepath)), else the full model is saved (model.save(filepath)). Therefore, based on the explanation provided on the following link I think its right to put false.
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/ModelCheckpoint

Comment: Hi @Fatima, after creating callbacks you have to train your model and then you have load weights using model.load_weights(checkpoint_path). For reference please refer to this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#checkpoint_callback_usage). Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same issue. As others have pointed out, the issue derives from the argument `save_weights_only=False` which creates a directory of files. You can still call `model.load_weights()` and depersist the model, but you get that unpleasant error. One approach I took was to use the following to depersist the model without any errors/warnings.

```
import tensorflow as tf

m = tf.keras.models.load_model('/path/to/checkpoint/dir')
```